# Radio button to filter another component using Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to filter in another component. And I'm new to this whole Vue and Vuex, so I'm sorry if my question is too much. Let's say I have this website

[image]

The radio button filters and filtered list are two different components. If I click a radio button, I want to get the value and pass it in Axios to fetch API using that value and show it in the filtered list component. Let's say I click a radio button with a value of 3, then my get method would be `axios.get('API-here.com/filter?type=' + 3)`.

My question is, how to achieve that using Vuex? So far, here's my code.

store/index.js

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    isChecked: '0',
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_CATEGORY(state, isChecked) {
      state.isChecked = isChecked;
    }
  }
}),
```

I also have this code, but I have no idea what file should I put this into.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    isChecked :{
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.isChecked;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit("SET_CATEGORY", value);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the filter isn't essential to your example so I'll skip that.  Create state for the api results and use an action to call the api and set those results in the store:

*Vuex*

```js
state: {
  results: []
},
mutations: {
  SET_RESULTS(state, results) {
    state.results = results;
  }
},
actions: {
  async setFilter({ commit }, filter) {
    const response = await axios.get('API-here.com/filter?type=' + filter);
    commit('SET_RESULTS', response.data);
    // commit('SET_FILTER', filter);
  }
}
```

When the radio button changes, dispatch the action:

*Radio component*

```html
<input type="radio" v-model="r" value="1" @change="changeFilter">
<input type="radio" v-model="r" value="2" @change="changeFilter">
<input type="radio" v-model="r" value="3" @change="changeFilter">
```

```js
methods: {
  changeFilter(e) {
    this.$store.dispatch('setFilter', e.target.value);
  }
}
```

Use the results in the other component:

*List component*

```html
{{ results }}
```

```js
computed: {
   ...mapState(['results'])
}
```

Comment: Works really smooth! Thanks a lot! Really learned so much from you.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, a string of the number 0 is true.  use `false` or the number `0`, not the string `'0'`.

For your filtered item data, use a computed property that references the store value.  It will update reactively.

```js
computed: {
filteredItems(){
  return this.items.filter(it => true) // todo reference your checkboxes to decide.
 }
}
```

For example, a checkbox that filters longer category lengths:

```
this.isChecked ? it.category.length > 5 : true
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I forgot to mention that 0 means "All list". Thank you for your answer!